# In laravel difference as describe below

Tags: laravel

(1). when i use `\Auth::user()->email`
need not to specify

```
use Auth;
```

at top of the file

(2). when i use only `Auth::user()->email`
need to specify

```
use Auth;
```

at top of the file.

which one is best for performance
(1). `\Auth` or
(2) `Auth`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guarantee you there are about 50,000 other optimizations with more value to your performance than this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, or at least any impact that you could observe.

```
use Auth;
```

Is better for file readers, sometimes when you need to refractor your code a look on use list make it faster to see what models are related to your controller.

Moreover you can set an alias to your included classes, like

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request as IlluminateRequest;
use Request as FacadeRequest;
```

Which comes in handy when dealing with specific cases.

Anyway, the short answer is that there is no difference that you can notice in terms of performance between both ways, and when you think twice then you can find more arguments for using a

```
use Auth;
```

solution.

Answer (score 1):

My general rule is if I'm only going to use the class once in a file, then I'll usually just prepend the `\` (like `\Auth::user()`.

However, if I use it twice or more, then I'll import it (`use Auth`);

That said, either is fine.